# ASP.NET MVC 5: Custom Login URL based on localized route parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.1

In ASP.NET MVC 5 you specify the login path URL in method `ConfigureAuth(...)` which is called from `Application_Start()`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
```

I need someway to specify the login path according to a localized route parameter.

One way I have in my mind is to redirect the user in `Application_AuthenticateRequest()` to the desired login page in case `Request.IsAuthenticated` is false. But I am not really sure whether this is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using OWIN, you can't assume the Application_AuthenticateRequest IIS programming model. You should assume OWIN's programming model.

Anyway, on the CookieAuthenticationOptions, there's a Provider property. On this there's a ApplyRedirect event you ca handle. In there you could alter the redirect URL.

Comment: See this question for more info on how to implement the ApplyRedirect: [MVC 5 How to define Owin LoginPath with localized routes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21660431/68940)