# .net Identity ignoring LoginPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

The title says it all really, my LoginPath is being completely ignored so every time I try to access an authorised page, it takes me to "/Account/Login" page that I've never defined anywhere rather than the "/Accounts" page I have defined. Not entirely sure why this has happened since it used to redirect me to the right place before and I haven't touched anything to do with authentication for a long time

Here's my Startup.Auth.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using App.Models;
using Owin;
using System;

namespace App
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Accounts"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                { 
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });

            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false" pageOutput="true" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: @SteveChapman MVC5 and Identity Framework 2.0.1

Comment: Have you tried what's suggested on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21660431/2293059)? Looks like a similar problem.

Comment: Can you provide your web.config (remove any sensitive data, passwords, ip addresses etc).

Comment: I've posted my web.config @ErikPhilips

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During an entire day of meditative debugging I found, that the reason of such weird behavior is WebMatrix.dll and WebMatrix.Data.dll. Even this libraries are NOT REFERENCED by  any project in solution and just lies in 'bin' folder, they inject SimpleMembership in Asp.NET pipeline causing this error.

Comment: Brilliant! Those two libraries are used by the .net web helpers library. I removed it and everything started working again

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one up vote for this answer. I agree it's brilliant.  Dropped that WebMatrix like a bag of bricks and I stopped redirecting to login.aspx?ReturnUrl=blah.  Woot!  Thanks for the "entire day of meditative debugging" and sure enough some serious headache.

Answer (score 3):

First, check your web.config.  Do these sections exist?

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="None" />
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />  - debug is not required obv.
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Make sure Authentication mode is None, and you remove the FormsAuthenticationModule.

Second, are you sure that you have an `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on the action method that /Accounts maps to.

Third,  Are you absolutely sure that your /Accounts route maps to the correct action?

You should probably use the UrlHelper to map to the correct url to be safe.

Comment: Added those bits to my web.config but it still hasn't done the trick. I've tried using the UrlHelper but again, it's still taking me to the wrong place.

/Accounts routes to the correct place, if I put the address in manually along with the ReturnUrl query string, it loads the page up and I can sign in and get returned to what I was trying to view

Comment: @Erik It might not have worked for Mo, but those bits + the WebMatix thing totally saved me! Thanks for saving me from more grief

Comment: The `authentication mode` was the problem in my case. Setting it to `None` and then adding the `remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"` made the `CookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath` work as I wanted. Thank you!